# Which font is this? And can it be used commercially for free?

Tags: fonts, font-identification, font-recommendation, font-licensing

A client, sent this logo as png to use it in a product I'm developing for him, I'm curious to know what font is this? He doesn't know, the online detection services are pretty close but the H is different, no service detects the H correctly.

I tried what's the font, Fontspring, and fontsquirrel.  If this isn't free, is there a free alternative like that?

[image]

Comment: It can well be a drawing, one which is built by taking parts of letters from one or more fonts. Many parts are found from font Strato pro Black. Some parts can have been drawn manually or they are edited font outlines. It's a common practice to design logos in that way.

Comment: @user287001 wowww good to know thank you!

Comment: Thanks. There are numerous other free and commercial fonts which have as well fitting parts. Be warned that some fonts are not allowed  to be used in logos. Some can deny all attempts to use in trademarked stuff. Read the license!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @user287001 Wow some can't be used in logos! Man you keep surprising me for real! it never occurred to me, Thanks for the letting me know!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [Goldenbook Black](https://www.marksimonson.com/fonts/view/goldenbook) by Mark Simonson, with some modification in the "H" – 
most probably H is modified with J.

[image]